# Translate batch script to Powershell script

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I currently have this script I run as a scheduled task:

```
@echo on
START /WAIT c:\windows\system32\Robocopy.exe "D:\folder" "\\192.168.2.87\folder" /E /MT:20 /R:50 /W:10 /V /ETA /LOG:c:\robocopy.txt
```

I want to convert and run this as a PowerShell script because of two reasons:

- Its more modern
- The most important reason is that I want to store the log with date and time as `C:\robocopylog3004201510214043.txt` and I am literally finding no information on how to strip characters like ":" and "/" from a batch script and I know PowerShell can.

That last number is not random. It is the date and time.

Date for example is "30/04/2015" (striping it would leave 30042015)
Time for example is "10:21:40,43" (striping it would leave 10214043)

So it would leave a file name of robocopylog3004201510214043.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is little difference between CMD and PowerShell when it comes to running external programs. I'd recommend using the call operator (`&`), though, even if it isn't mandatory in this particular case.

```
& c:\windows\system32\Robocopy.exe "D:\folder" "\\192.168.2.87\folder" /E /MT:20 /R:50 /W:10 /V /ETA /LOG:c:\robocopy$(Get-Date -format 'ddMMyyyyHHmmss').txt
```

`robocopy` runs synchronously anyway, so no "wait" instruction required.

The [number format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `ddMMyyyyHHmmss` produces a timestamp consisting of day, month, year, hour, minutes and seconds. I wouldn't recommend to include milliseconds as well, because you probably won't run robocopy several times within the same second. If you must include milliseconds, append `ff` to the format string (or `f`, `fff`, etc., depending on the number of digits you need). You may want to consider using an ISO date format (`yyyyMMddHHmmss`), though, because that simplifies listing the log files in creation order.

As for replacing characters in batch scripts, that can be done via [string replacements](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshpoley/archive/2011/06/03/batch-file-string-substitution-with-nested-environment-variables.aspx):

```
C:\>echo %DATE:/=%
30042015

C:\>echo %TIME::=_%
10_01_22.39
```

Comment: Currently, the batch script is returning a date of "30/04/2015" and "10:21:40,43". So I want to remove the "/", the ":" and the ",". It would be as 3004201510214043. Ill add this to the original question.

Comment: & c:\windows\system32\Robocopy.exe "D:\folder" "\\192.168.2.87\folder" /E /MT:20 /R:50 /W:10 /V /ETA /LOG:c:\robocopy$(Get-Date -format 'ddMMyyyHHmmssfff').txt

Comment: What exactly is the "&" for?

Comment: Like I said: it's the call operator. It allows you to run executables in double quotes (`& "C:\path\to\some\executable"`). Without the call operator PowerShell would consider a path between quotes a string and simply echo it to the default output stream. It's not required in this particular case, because the path to your executable isn't in quotes.

Comment: Yeah, i actually went for that format instead of the one I originally commented as it seemed clearer. I include MS because I do indeed do several robocopies on the same second.